# How do you loop through every Checkbox in Div? (dart)

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have a div in my html:

```dart
<div id="list_container_id"></div>
```

To which I add Checkbox(es) through dart

```dart
CheckboxInputElement cie = new CheckboxInputElement();
LabelElement label = new LabelElement();
    cie.id="checkboxid_"+asdf;//unique id
    label.htmlFor = 'checkboxid_'+asdf;//bind Label to checkbox
    label.text = asdf;
    list_container.children.add(cie);
    list_container.children.add(label);
    list_container.children.add(new Element.html("<br>"));//linebreak after the checkbox
```

later, I want to get a list of all values of the Checkboxes that are checked on Button click. The following code happens onClick:

```dart
List list = [];    
for (CheckboxInputElement elem in list_container.children){
        if(elem.checked){
          list.add(elem.value);
        }
      }
```

As far as I understand it, that for loop goes trough every Checkbox that is in the list_container, but for some reason, it throws an Error when it reaches a label:

> Breaking on exception: type 'LabelElement' is not a subtype of type
>   'CheckboxInputElement' of 'elem'.

I don't understand why the for loop even bothers with the Labels when I stated clearly that elem should be a CheckboxInputElement. How would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state that it only should return `CheckboxInputElement` you state that the variable holding the values processed in the loop should only hold `CheckboxInputElement`s but the loop assigns every element it encounters.

This way you get only `CheckboxInputElement`

```dart
List list = [];    
for (var elem in list_container.children.where((e) => e is CheckboxInputElement)){
  if(elem.checked){
    list.add(elem.value);
  }
}
```

or

```dart
list.addAll(list_container.children
  .where((e) => e is CheckboxInputElement && e.checked)
  .map((e) => e.value));
```

or

```dart
list.addAll(querySelectorAll('#list_container_id input[type="checkbox"]')
  .where((e) => e is CheckboxInputElement && e.checked)
  .map((e) => e.value));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
querySelector("#list_container_id")
    .querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
        .forEach((CheckboxInputElement e) {
            /* do work */ 
         });
```